# What would be the reverse of this function, to undo the transformation it performs?

Tags: vector, hlsl, coordinate-transformation

I have this HLSL function:

```
float3 transform(float3 pos, float3 XYZ) {
                float3 v = K * cross(XYZ, pos);
                float f = 1.0 - K * dot(XYZ, pos);
                float3 y = a + b;

                return (y * f + cross(v, y)) / (f * f + dot(v, v));
```

this function transforms a float3 position to a final position, using a second float3 as input. For example:

```
worldpos = transform(worldpos, addVector);
```

What would be the function that reverses this transformation? Such that it brings the transformed position back to its original position?

I have worked out the function into a single line of operations:

pos = (XYZ + pos) * (1 - K * dot(XYZ, pos)) + cross(K * cross(XYZ, pos)), (XYZ + pos)) / (pow(1.0 - K * dot(XYZ, pos)), 2.0)  + dot(K * cross(XYZ, pos), K * cross(XYZ, pos)));

Thank you for your help!

I just cannot work out the math.